# How to parse Json to class in c# (Windows phone 8)?

Tags: c#, json

Maybe someone knows better version to resolve my problem?

Have next json:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":{  
         "IsEmpty":false,
         "X":-10.5,
         "Y":2.47
      },
      "password":"pas"
   },
   {  
      "name":{  
         "IsEmpty":false,
         "X":-10.5,
         "Y":2.47
      },
      "password":"pas"
   },
   {  
      "name":{  
         "IsEmpty":false,
         "X":-10.5,
         "Y":2.47
      },
      "password":"pas"
   }
]
```

I want parse elements from json to my classes:

```
 public class Name
    {
        public bool IsEmpty { get; set; }
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Name> name { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

......

```
    dynamic res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(result1);
```

Variable result1 is my json object.

And exeption, what I have:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'client_app.MainPage+RootObject[]' because the type requires
>   a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this
>   error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change
>   the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a
>   primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or
>   List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'name', line 1, position 8.

Comment: Please add newlines and tabs to the json to make it readable

Answer (score 1):

The problem resides in the mapping between your JSon string and your root object. I think that this is what causes the problem:

```
"IsEmpty":false
```

When deserializing your object the JSon converter waits for the IsEmpty property to be of type *bool*.
Which is not the case since its type is *List*

So your root class should be like this:

```
     public class RootObject
     {
        public Name name { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
     }
```

Comment: this is mistake, my fail

Comment: @user2508630 Do you mean that it does not help?

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
 var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(result1);
```

Comment: @user2508630 Please change your RootObject class. Name propery should not be a list. I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the set of classes you need to deserialize

```
public class Name
{
    public bool IsEmpty { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
var items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item[]>(json);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var ds = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject[]));
                var msnew = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MyJsonString));
                RootObject[] items = (RootObject[])ds.ReadObject(msnew);
```

This resolve my problem

Comment: whilst this may of solved your issue you have offered absolutely no explanation as to why you need to use a MemoryStream. Three people here offered valid responses to your question, and whilst they may not have solved your problem they did offer correct ideas as to what the problem may of been. Namely, that your C# objects did not match your Json structure.

Answer (score -2):

Your `Name` class has the property of `IsEmpty` as a List of `bools`.

So you Json should be:

```
[
{
    "name": {
        "IsEmpty": [
            false
        ],
        "X": -10.5,
        "Y": 2.47
    },
    "password": "pas"
},
{
    "name": {
        "IsEmpty": [
            false
        ],
        "X": -10.5,
        "Y": 2.47
    },
    "password": "pas"
},
{
    "name": {
        "IsEmpty": [
            false
        ],
        "X": -10.5,
        "Y": 2.47
    },
    "password": "pas"
}
```

]

Note the sqaure brackets on the value of `IsEmpty`, which signifies the value is in a collection. if you want to assign more than one value then you can add more using:

```
"IsEmpty": [ false, true ]
```